# No output with uinput

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, uinput

When I run this example code from [uinput](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput):

```
import uinput

device = uinput.Device([
        uinput.KEY_E,
        uinput.KEY_H,
        uinput.KEY_L,
        uinput.KEY_O,
        ])

device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_H)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_E)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_L)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_L)
device.emit_click(uinput.KEY_O)
```

I expect the word `HELLO` to appear, but I see nothing. I tried:

```
modprobe uinput
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm on Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: is there any error message ?

Comment: @Dadep no, the code executes succesfully